# Getting the value of selected value from drop-down grails

Tags: grails

I have `g:select` like this:

```
<g:select from="["A1 Negative(A1 -ve)","A1 Positive(A1 +ve)"]" noSelection ="${['null':'Please choose . . . ']}" name = "bloodGroups"
                            value="${donorDetailsInstance?.bloodGroups}" />
```

This is inside a form and when I try to click button and look for the value selected by the user I'm getting `null`.

I'm trying to do get the selected value using:

```
params.bloodGroups
```

in my controller but its always returning `null`.

Where I'm making the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you remove the noSelection?

Comment: You can try using developer tools in chrome and make sure request parmeters has 'bloodGroups' parameter with selected value

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass an object into from

```
<g:select from="${["A1 Negative(A1 -ve)","A1 Positive(A1 +ve)"]}" noSelection="${['null':'Please choose . . . ']}" name="bloodGroups" value="${donorDetailsInstance?.bloodGroups}" />
```